# How can I run multiple UNIX commands, using an input file, just once

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I'm relatively novice in Unix Shell Scripting. 
How can I run the (following) multiple UNIX commands (put into a script, say "discover.sh", using `my_log.txt` input-file just once? Eventually, I would like to create an alias [alias discover1='~/discover.sh'] in my .bashrc.

Like:

```
$ discover1 my_log.txt
```

Current script:

```
/bin/egrep 'Version:|Online \(warning\)|Failed \(offline\)' my_log.txt;
/bin/grep -A7 "syscontrol realmmgr" my_log.txt;
/bin/grep -C2 BIOS my_log.txt;
```

Comment: Why would you want that as an alias instead of creating a shell script in your `$HOME/bin` directory, which should be on your `$PATH`? There probably are ways to cat the file just once, especially in `bash`.  I'm not sure whether they're worth using.  For example: `cat my_log.txt | tee >(/bin/egrep 'Version...') >(/bin/grep -A7 "...") | /bin/grep -C BIOS`. This loses control over the sequencing of the output (you could get partial lines from different processes). If you really want to scan the file just once, I suggest using Perl do the searches all at once. Not quite trivial, but pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

`discover.sh` should contain:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/egrep 'Version:|Online \(warning\)|Failed \(offline\)' "$1"
/bin/grep -A7 "syscontrol realmmgr" "$1";
/bin/grep -C2 BIOS "$1";
```

The variable `$1` is automatically set to the first parameter of the script.

Comment: Any reason not to use `"$@"` in place of `"$1"`?  It's more general if you process any number of files (other than zero).  It isn't entirely clear that it is safe if there is no argument; arguably, the script should check that there is at least a `"$1"` to work on.

Comment: These are both reasonable.